# how to change style of a part of string when click :Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I will change style a part of string when click. example "TEXT" then click at "T" after that it will change style from black color to red color just T only
In my code, I split text and keep at "split" array when I click at text, it will call handleClick function and send index of character that I click is parameter. For example ("EXAMPLE") when I click E it will send 0 is parameter of handleClick function.

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'
export default class Test extends Component {
    handleClick = (index) => {
        console.log(index)
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                {this.state.table.map((text) => {{this.state.split 
                    && this.state.split.map((item, index) => { 
                        return(
                            <span key={index} onClick={() => 
                                this.handleClick(index)}>{item} 
                            </span>
                         );
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a state which will maintain the clicked index. Then use that index while rendering your split spans to set different colored className.
You could then apply your style to that class.

```
export default class Test extends Component {

    handleClick = (index) => {
        this.setState({ clickedIndex: index });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.table.map((text) => {
                    this.state.split && this.state.split.map((item, index) => {
                        return (
                            <span key={index} style={clickedIndex === index ? {color: 'red'} : {}} onClick={() =>
                                this.handleClick(index)}>{item}
                            </span>
                        );
                    })
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```